# How to germinate Rudbeckia laciniata?

Tags: germination

Does anyone have any tips on germinating Rudbeckia laciniata? I have tried seed from a variety of sources, sown it indoors and out, with stratification and without, with bottom heat and without, covered and uncovered - and had no success whatsoever.

Comment: There's this: https://npn.rngr.net/renderNPNProtocolDetails?selectedProtocolIds=compositae-rudbeckia-1727

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the resources for quite such fine control over the growing environment as that, but I can stratify in the fridge and then start in a heated propagator. Perhaps the issue is the different transition from winter to summer conditions between a continental climate like the UP and the maritime one here (Scotland).